# How to kill running threads and keep perl application alive?

Tags: multithreading, perl

Using `async` for **threads** in **perl** script I need to do some parallel functionality, however I have to set a fix time limit for such threads (e.g. max 5 sec). I need to kill all runing threads if they are running for longer, but still **keep program alive**. My code is:

```
use threads ( 'yield',
              'exit' => 'threads_only',
              'stack_size' => 2*16384 );
use threads::shared;
use Time::HiRes qw/sleep/;

...

$start = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
my $running :shared = 0;
foreach ($entry) {
  async(
    sub {
           local $SIG{KILL} = sub { threads->exit };
           { lock $running; ++$running };

           ...

           { lock $running; --$running };
        },
  $_)->detach;
}

while ($running) {
  sleep 0.005;
  last if (Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start) > 5);
}

if ($running) {
  my @running = threads->list(threads::running);
  foreach (@running) {
    $_->kill('KILL')->detach;
  }
}

print "I am still alive\n";
```

Is there some better way how to **kill running threads** and keep application alive?

Comment: Surely there's a better way to track five seconds time than busy-waiting for it.

Comment: But you're chewing at least one core to death doing nothing but checking the time. That's expensive in both heat and power. I made the comment in the hopes that someone else who knows Perl better than I do will notice my comment and give advice on replacing it with more efficient code -- something they might have missed if they just answer your question directly.

Comment: @sarnold - I understand, but so far anyone else claims that waiting is wrong and nobody came with alternative solution. What else you can do if you need to wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Code the threads so that they only do work that you want done and terminate themselves when there's no work for them to do. Don't try to go in from the outside and kill them. That never works well.

Comment: What is wrong about killing threads? When you have internal time-out for some work, there is no other way, just kill those slow threads...

Comment: My threads finish the job in 99.999% on time and terminate themselves, but if not, I have to kill them, as I need resources they block. Understood?

Comment: @stackoverflow: You are writing the code those threads are running. Code them to do what you want to do, code them to terminate if they are no longer needed. Then you won't need to kill them. It's not the threads that are slow, it's the work that's taking too long. You are focusing on the threads when the issue is the work.

Comment: @stackoverflow, It might free some resources, but I doubt it would free all of them -- I especially doubt that it would free locks -- and it can leave the process in a wonky state. You should be using processes if you want to do some killing, not threads.

Comment: @ikegami - Thread lock `running` variable just at the begining, so there should be no problem with lock hold. Why do you believe killing of threads would not free resources they use? Can you show us some code that would use processes?

Comment: @stackoverflow: The thread may have allocated memory and killing the thread gives it no chance to free it. The thread may have opened a file descriptor, and killing the thread gives it no chance to close it. Killing a thread is just boneheaded. If you even feel like you slightly want to do it, that honestly strongly suggests that you fundamentally don't understand threading. A process is a set of cooperating threads -- killing a thread is like shooting yourself. If you need a competitive/isolated model, use processes, not threads.

Comment: @David Schwartz - there is no real thread killing. See the code. I am just sending a signal which force threads to terminate themselves. So there is normal thread termination, which I believe free all alocated memories used by such thread. Am I wrong?

Comment: @stackoverflow: No, that will probably work, but it's still awful. Don't code the thread to block indefinitely in the first place and then you won't need to send it a signal from the outside.

Comment: @David Schwartz - I hear you. You want to tell me that you never ever needed to force threads for earlier terminations?

Comment: @stackoverflow: No, I never did, nor would that ever make any sense. I might want to stop processing of a particular job, but that would be an operation on the job and I wouldn't kludge it as a thread operation.

Comment: I think killing a thread wouldn't free all resources freeing some of those resources would require running some code, and you just killed the code that could free them.  It's not like the OS can free them since the process that owns them is still running. I tried to do some testing, but everytime I try to kill a thread, my progrm SEGFAULTs. Which brings me to the second thing I said: It's just not safe. That's why Java dropped the ability to kill threads.

Comment: @ikegami - Take a closer look - threads are not killed, just forced to terminate themselves by sending KILL signal. And regular termination should free all allocated resources. And because from Perl 5.8. signals are safe, it should be all safe.

Comment: @stackoverflow, ok, that's much better. But that means `thread->kill` won't interrupt blocked system calls and XS code, so it might not do anything at all. No idea why I got a segfault using it, then...

Comment: @ikegami - No segfault with my code. What is your (entire) code? Perhaps you should open a new question with your issue and send us a link to it, so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

async returns a thread object that you can call kill on. Just push them onto an array and kill them afterwards.

http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

A better design would probably be to have the threads kill themselves after that amount of time though.

Comment: Threads terminate themselves once they finish the job on time. The advantage of checking timeout from main program is that if for whatever reason thread hang out, it will be killed anyway. In case thread checks its timeout, I cannot be sure it will always terminate. Besides of that, what you see as an advantage to keep own array of threads from async returns and not to use `threads->list(threads::running)` instead?

Comment: @stackoverflow: Using the list of running threads is a bad model because it loses the information about what the threads are doing, forcing you to keep track of every thread your code creates, and what it's doing, in one centralized place, robbing you of flexibility in assigning work to threads. Focusing on the threads is a bad mindset to get into and leads to very bad code -- focus on the work that needs to get done and treat threads as just a tool. Think of threads like workers working on a house -- you want to manage the construction of the house, not the workers.

Comment: @David Schwartz - I understand what you are saying, but you don't see a code of threads, so you don't see whole picture. The issue is that threads are doing some jobs that might eventually hang, due to errors or issues from other party they are communicate with. And as you can see in my code, I am not killing threads, I am just sending them a signal, based on which they terminate themselves. So there is not real threads killing, just forcing for termination(s). Am I still wrong? If so, tell me what exactly is wrong and why exactly.

Comment: @stackoverflow: If the code of the threads is broken, fix it. Don't try to fix it from the outside, fix the broken code itself. If you don't want a thread to block indefinitely, don't code it to block indefinitely. All threads in a process must cooperate.

Comment: @David Schwartz - I cannot fix errors of the other party which my threads communicate with - that is remote code on the other server. I hope you understand that. And I believe sending signal to force termination is exactly what prevent my threads to block indefinitely.

Comment: @stackoverflow: It's not the thread that blocks indefinitely, it's the function you call to wait for the other party. Why did you code a thread to wait indefinitely if you didn't want it to wait indefinitely? That's what forced you to persuade it to stop from the outside. Just don't code it to wait indefinitely in the first place, and then you don't need to persuade it from the outside.

Comment: @David Schwartz - Thread job contains no loop, they terminate soon or later anyway. The only factor that can lead to make their job slow is network delays as all the thread job is just parsing of bunch of http requests and reponses. The only allocation is a `HTTP::Request` object, which I believe is freed on thread termination. Maybe I can add some more strict timeout restriction to `HTTP:Request` handling, so then technically thread will terminate its job always on-time... Any further sugestions?

Comment: @stackoverflow If you don't want the job to run forever, code the job itself not to run forever. Kludging it from the outside is awful and commits you to a clumsy design. (Imagine, for example, if a later design of the HTTP code uses a helper thread or defers the job asynchronously with no associated thread for a time.)